# SAST vs WAF: What should I choose?

Tags: waf, sdlc

Given the fact that I have a WAF already deployed, what is the benefit I could get by purchasing a SAST tool that would scan the engineers' code for security flaws?

Does this also apply for SCA tools where they can alert in case of using a vulnerable/malicious dependency or library? Can WAFs also protect from that?

Comment: *Given that I already have a safety belt, why should I also have a regular technical inspection of the car?* -  WAF and SAST complement each other. And a WAF might detect some vulnerably JavaScript library you serve but it will not detect vulnerable libraries you use in your back end.

Comment: @elenaa your title says one or the other, but the wording in your question body suggests an added benefit. Which are you asking about?

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Shall I update the title then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WAF (Web application firewall) is meant to **protect an already deployed application** independently of the underlying application.

SAST (Static Application Security Testing) is meant to scan your code and find known vulnerabilities **based on code**.

DAST (Dynamic Application Security Testing) is meant to scan your already deployed application and find known vulnerabilities **based on a live running instance**.

SCA (Software Composition Analysis) is meant to **analyze third party dependencies** for known vulnerabilities.

Don't mix them up, there is no WAF vs SAST/DAST. WAF is meant to be application independent, you could potentially have a vulnerable application, but because you have a WAF in front of it, you still are protected.

An ideal devops environment would involve all of the tools mentioned, although, a potential debate here could be DAST vs SAST, but this is out of scope of the question.

Comment: Really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 4):

**SAST** has several advantages:

- can be deployed quickly
- requires little to no maintenance
- remediations can be done faster
- minimizes the need for post-release patches and security updates
- has better overall RoI
- can also be used for scanning real time systems, mobile applications and software 
  present on embedded devices
- false positives don't affect you

So if you can go SAST, you should certainly do it.

Comment: How about already cloud deployed WAF?? Maintenance does not burden us.

Comment: Maintenance is dependent on a lot of factors, if your it's low, it's a happy case. A good WAF implementation needs dedicated staff to continuously tweak and configure it; additional personnel is needed to sort out FPs and properly send them to the devs, which devs in turn may or may not be familiar with the app's source code.